# how to add vertical line on left side of listview after selecting checkbox in android

Tags: android

Image shows listview which contains checkbox and after selecting checkbox ,green verticle line will appear on left side of listrow .
how to create that line?
thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add that vertical line in your list_item.xml and set visibility View.GONE by default,
when you check any item of list just set visibility View.VISIBLE in your checkbox listener

```
<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#119292"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In custom list item xml, add view for vertical line with green color and set transparency to `transparent`. After checkbox is checked set transparency to `opaque`.